# java applet hotkeys

Tags: java, applet, hotkeys

I was curious if it was possible to create hotkeys in a jApplet that are global for the applet...like a global key handler or something. 
For example, I would like to be able to press the key, 'F11' lets say, then have a jPanel appear, and then press 'f11' again to make it disappear... regardless of which component I'm focused on.I don't expect it to work when I'm not focused on the application, just within.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/).